# Не кликабельные элементы группы ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, expandablelistview

Элементы группы не раскрываются, данные в адаптер приходят. Делал по этому примеру - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419446/adding-expandablelistview-to-navigationview
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HomeView {
@BindView(R.id.drawer_layout)
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
@BindView(R.id.navigationmenu)
ExpandableListView expandableListView;
@BindView(R.id.nav_view)
NavigationView navigationView;
@BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
RecyclerView recyclerView;

ExpandableListAdapter menuAdapter;
private HashMap<ExpandedMenuModel, List<String>> listDataChild;
private List<ExpandedMenuModel> listDataHeader;

private HomePresenter presenter;
private RecyclerViewHomeAdapter homeAdapter;
private List<ShopData.Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
private static int page = 1;
public static boolean isLoading;

public static void setIsLoading(boolean isLoading) {
    HomeActivity.isLoading = isLoading;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    if (navigationView != null) {
        setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
    }

    presenter = new HomePresenter(this);
    isLoading = true;
    presenter.getData(page);
    homeAdapter = new RecyclerViewHomeAdapter(items, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(homeAdapter);

    prepareListDataMenu();
    menuAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild, expandableListView);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(menuAdapter);

    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, int i1, long l) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "submenu item clicked");
            return false;
        }
    });
    expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "heading clicked");
            return false;
        }
    });

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerViewOnScroll() {
        @Override
        public void loadMore() {
            if (isLoading) {
                if (page < 3) {
                    page += 1;
                    presenter.getData(page);
                    isLoading = false;
                    homeAdapter.setItemList(items);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
private void prepareListDataMenu() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<>();

    ExpandedMenuModel item1 = new ExpandedMenuModel();
    item1.setHeaderName("heading1");

    // Adding data header
    listDataHeader.add(item1);

    ExpandedMenuModel item2 = new ExpandedMenuModel();
    item2.setHeaderName("heading2");
    listDataHeader.add(item2);

    List<String> heading1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    heading1.add("Submenu of item 1");

    List<String> heading2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    heading2.add("Submenu of item 2");
    heading2.add("Submenu of item 2");
    heading2.add("Submenu of item 2");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), heading1);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), heading2);
}
private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void setDataList(List<ShopData.Item> itemList) {
    items.addAll(itemList);
    homeAdapter.setItemList(items);
}

@Override
public void onErrorLoading(String message) {
    Utils.showDialogMessage(this, "Tittle", message);
}}
```

activity_home.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.home.HomeActivity"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/navigationmenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white">
        </ExpandableListView>
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

listheader.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconimage"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/submenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

list_submenu.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/submenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: покажите xml файл

Comment: @MartinezToni, добавил xml

Comment: а они я так понимаю отображаются,общие элементы? Но не кликабельные? А должны кликаться и раскрываться?

Comment: @MartinezToni, не раскрываются вложенные элементы внутри ExpandableListView при нажатии на заголовки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо любой компонент графического интерфейса переместит перед виджетов `NavigationView`, для меня это `RecyclerView`, и это решает проблему раскрывания элементов внутри `ExpandableListView`. 
Может кто-нибудь объяснить почему так?

**activity_home.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.home.HomeActivity"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >
        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/navigationmenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            >
        </ExpandableListView>
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю,что у вашего элемента списка,есть элементы которые беру фокус на себя.

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Это должно решить проблему.

Comment: При добавлении данного параметра ничего не изменилось, происходит тоже самое при нажатии на заголовок NavigationView просто сворачивается

Comment: @neyasbit попробуйте слушатели убрать

Comment: также не помогло, возможно это можно как-то отдебажить? Просто я вообще без идей почему не работает.